# How to programmatically adjust ASCII art for Instagram's text handling and avoid disorientation

Tags: android, instagram, ascii-art

I'm developing an app that allows users to copy ASCII art and paste it wherever they need. I prompt users to specify the final destination, such as the comment section on Instagram, as most of the text will be shared there. However, there are issues with character disorientation for certain ASCII art. While I can manually adjust a few instances, there are numerous cases where it's not feasible to verify the proper display on Instagram.

I attempted to resolve this by adding 
 tags as replacements for newlines (/n), but this approach only works effectively for webpages and not apps.

Adapter Class

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MemeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
            yourClass.intertitalAd(context);

            final String meme = memeList.get(position);

            holder.memeTextView.setText(meme);
            if (position == 0) {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false)) {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.copyImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.lockImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            holder.copyImageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                try {
                    String newAsciiArt = meme.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
                    clickCounter++;
                    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("meme", newAsciiArt);
                    if (clickCounter == 2) {
                        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show(binding);
                        }

                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Unless you can define what instagram does, that's going to be impossible to answer.  It could also change at any time, if they change anything about their text layout code or the font.  Even then it will probably display slightly differently on every phone.

Comment: so will it make sense to make the app in general

Comment: It is even unclear what you wanna adjust to begin with. Automatically or not.